# AWS platform. Picking the right technologies

Tags: postgresql, react-native, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am building an app that allows people to share items with other people in the community. I wanted to use AWS as my platform.

My idea was to use react Native for the app. AWS Cognito for the authentication. AWS lambda for the server calls. Relational database for storing data about the items and user data such as geolocation. Dynamodb for real-time chat, requests for borrowing and transaction data between users. My primary focus is low cost and I was thinking of using PostgresSQL for relational database.

What do you guys think of my database choices. Of course the PostgresSQL database on rds. Is there a flaw in database plan so far? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just use DynamoDB for everything in your application. I don't see a real need to storing some of your data in an RDS database here. However if you definitely need a relational database, I would suggest [AWS Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) so that your entire application would be using serverless AWS services. Also, normal relational database connection pools don't work that well in AWS Lambda, so I would suggest using the new [Data API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-data-api-for-amazon-aurora-serverless/).